# Different functions, same result

Tags: python, setattr

So I'm trying to dynamically set properties to a class with different names where each property makes a unique call to my database. However, when I access the property objects, all of them return the same result despite looking up on different columns with completely different values each. Here is the code:

```
class Configs:

    def __init__(self, guild_id):
        self.guild_id = guild_id

for x in configs:

    def fget(self):
        return cur.execute(f'SELECT {x.name} FROM configs WHERE guild_id = ?', (self.guild_id,)).fetchone()[0], x.name

    def fset(self, value):
        cur.execute(f'UPDATE configs SET {x.name} = ? WHERE guild_id = ?', (value, self.guild_id))
        con.commit()

    setattr(Configs, x.name, property(fget, fset))
```

The configs variable is a list of objects where each object has a `name` attribute which points to a string. The result is always the one that the last element of the configs array would produce, I suspect this is happening because `x.name` is used to make the calls and once the for loop is done, x remains as the last element of the array.

Comment: What is `x`? is it a `Configs` ? Where do you set the value of `x.name` ?

Comment: `x` is a simple object with a single `name` attribute that has a string pre-assigned to it. I'm constructing these objects in another part of the code. `configs` is just a list with 3 or more of these objects.

Comment: So you're trying to set a property, called whatever is the value of `x.name`, that reads and writes from the database when it is accessed? Like an active record?

Comment: Not really, I'm trying to create a property that makes a call to the database and returns a value whenever it's accessed and I can also update the database with a simple assignment syntax.

Comment: Is that not what I said?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant that I was keeping a record of the results whenever the properties were accessed. Then, yes I am trying to do what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are under the false impression that defining a function binds the function to the variable values at time of defining.  This sounds complex, sorry.  I'll try to explain.

You are defining functions in a loop (`fget`, `fset`).  In the functions you use a variable of the loop (`x`).  This will work, but not in the way you expect it to work.  All functions will be exactly alike, always accessing the value of a global variable `x` *at the time of their calling*.  The value at the time of defining will not be taken into consideration.

See for example this:

```
a = []
for i in range(3):
  def f(): return i
  a.append(f)

a[0]()  # will return 2
del i
a[0]()  # will raise a NameError because there is no i anymore
```

To solve your issue you need to pass the value at time of defining into the functions:

```
def fget(self, x=x):
    return cur.execute(f'SELECT {x.name} FROM configs WHERE guild_id = ?', (self.guild_id,)).fetchone()[0], x.name

def fset(self, value, x=x):
    cur.execute(f'UPDATE configs SET {x.name} = ? WHERE guild_id = ?', (value, self.guild_id))
    con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow what you're trying to do, you're quite correct that when your properties are called, they will use whatever is the current value of `x.name` (which will be whatever it was left at at the end of your loop).

Here is a possible way to fix it: assign `x.name` to another variable that your property functions have access to. A default argument might work well for that.

```
for x in configs:

    def fget(self, col_name=x.name):
        return cur.execute(f'SELECT {col_name} FROM configs WHERE guild_id = ?', (self.guild_id,)).fetchone()[0], col_name

    def fset(self, value, col_name=x.name):
        cur.execute(f'UPDATE configs SET {col_name} = ? WHERE guild_id = ?', (value, self.guild_id))
        con.commit()

    setattr(Configs, x.name, property(fget, fset))
```